# Oracle SQL group by then sum

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table `CUST_LOG` with data below.

```
+----+---------+--------+
| ID | CUST_ID | STATUS |
+----+---------+--------+
|  1 |       1 |      1 |
|  2 |       1 |      2 |
|  3 |       2 |      2 |
|  4 |       3 |      3 |
|  5 |       1 |      1 |
|  6 |       1 |      2 |
|  7 |       1 |      3 |
|  8 |       2 |      1 |
|  9 |       2 |      2 |
+----+---------+--------+
```

How should I select above as below result? I want to group by `CUST_ID` then sum each status count by `CUST_ID`? I used `OUTER JOIN` but not work.

```
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
| CUST_ID | STATUS_1 | STATUS_2 | STATUS_3 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
|       1 |        2 |        2 |        1 |
|       2 |        1 |        2 |        0 |
|       3 |        0 |        0 |        1 |
+---------+----------+----------+----------+
```

The only way I found is use `UNION` clause as the following sql, but it is too complicated if there are many status.

```sql
select CUST_ID, SUM(STATUS_1) as STATUS_1, SUM(STATUS_2) as STATUS_2, SUM(STATUS_3) as STATUS_3 from (
    select CUST_ID, COUNT(ID) as STATUS_1, 0 as STATUS_2, 0 as STATUS_3 from CUST_LOG where STATUS = 1 group by CUST_ID 
    union
    select CUST_ID, 0 as STATUS_1, COUNT(ID) as STATUS_2, 0 as STATUS_3 from CUST_LOG where STATUS = 2 group by CUST_ID
    union
    select CUST_ID, 0 as STATUS_1, 0 as STATUS_2, COUNT(ID) as STATUS_3 from CUST_LOG where STATUS = 3 group by CUST_ID

) group by CUST_ID;
```

Comment: Could a given `CUST_ID` ever have the same status value appearing _more_ than once?

Comment: Yes, the status will have many times of a `CUST_ID`

Comment: My question is the other way around.  Could a given `CUST_ID`, for example, ever have status = 1 more than once?

Comment: Yes, for example, `CUST_ID= 1` may have `STATUS` = 1 more then once.

Comment: Then the answer you accepted will not always generate the correct result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following, here is the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qN669RK1hjVnNZPyhnAvKv/0).

```
select
    cust_id,
    sum(case when status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) status_1,
    sum(case when status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) status_2,
    sum(case when status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) status_3
from cust_log
group by
    cust_id
order by
    cust_id
```

Output:

```
| cust_id | status_1 | status_2 | status_3 |
| ------- | -------- | -------- | -------- |
| 1       | 1        | 1        | 0        |
| 2       | 0        | 1        | 0        |
| 3       | 0        | 0        | 1        |
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a pivot query:

```
SELECT
    CUST_ID,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 1 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS STATUS_1,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 2 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS STATUS_2,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN STATUS = 3 THEN 1 END) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS STATUS_3
FROM CUST_LOG
GROUP BY
    CUST_ID
ORDER BY
    CUST_ID;
```

Comment: Could a given `CUST_ID` ever have the same status value appearing more than once?